# How can I communicate with a REV robot control hub through wifi?

Tags: java, android

I have a REV robot kit from the First Global Challenge competition. It has a control hub which runs Android and creates an own network. I can connect that wifi with my phone and I can upload a program. But if I am connected to that network, I am offline and I can't send web requests to communicate with my server. Is there any way to solve this? I have a router, maybe it can help.

Comment: If you are participating in FIRST isn't [WiFi against the rules](https://frc-qa.firstinspires.org/eventrules/rule/E/12)?

Comment: I was participating in FIRST, but I want to use the robot for a home project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this currently is to connect a USB WiFi adapter to your computer, which will allow you to connect to a second network.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by connecting to the REV Controller's WIFI with my laptop, and then I plugged the ethernet cable in my computer.